# Create style ranges in HTML code for fusion tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm having trouble to implement style ranges in my html code. Im implementing google fusion tables in a html, where i want a color for a certain polygon who's value falls within a range of numbers. So the color red for every polygon within the range of 1-10. I know how to use > or <= but I cant find the right code for ranging. here is the sample:

```js
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: "KML",
        from: "1uYmJOaw2DGBur0f4tJxRcKbu1FbakZUxCdR1yLgL14"
    },
    templateId: 2,
    styles: [
        {
            where: 'col2 = 0',
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#999999',
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            }
        },
        {
            where: 'col2 = 1-10',
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#ea9999',
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            }
        }
    ]
});
layer.setMap(map);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that you can do exactly this with bucket styles in the UI. There are things the layer styling can do that the UI can't, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

To get a range you need to combine the operators you already know with `AND`:

```js
{
    where: 'col2 >= 1 AND col2 <= 10', //equals all numbers from 1 to 10
    polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#ea9999',
        fillOpacity: 0.3
    }
}
```